# Time schedule algorithm

Tags: node.js, algorithm

I have been trying for some time solve a scheduling problem for an App that I used to work at. This problem is as follows...

First time the list gets populated:

- will look at all contacts that a user has made “Active” in the Contacts list.
- For each, it should look at their selected contact frequency (e.g. x days, x weeks, x months.)
- will compare their “last contact date” with today’s date.  For any contact where the difference between these dates is greater than their assigned contact frequency, the person is a candidate to be added to the Agent list.

The order of how people will appear on the Agent list should adhere to the following rules:

- Contacts with longest gap between last contact are higher on the list
- Contacts marked as Favorite go to the top of the list
- isApp users take priority

From this list of “candidates”, the algorithm should then also review contact history for each. For contacts with the following assigned contact frequency, follow these rules

- Every x Days – Do not take history into account.  Just add when they’re past due
- Every x Weeks – if contact already within the last 3 days, do not show, and skip to the next time they will be up for contacting.
- Every x Months – if contact already within the last 7 days, do not show, and skip to the next time they will be up for contacting.
- Every x Year – if contacted in the last month, do not show, and skip to the next time they will be up for contacting.

Comment: sounds like "some work for me".

Answer (score 3):

Create a data set array that includes all the contacts. Add filters for the contacts for example "active". Set a period for contacts to differentiate according to gaps. Create a default category and add all the contact in it so then you can iterate to skip contacts from last 7 days or so. Once you have a default array you can always create another list with desired features. In this case the same list will be processed with four conditions such as required in last 4 your lines. This solution is generic for any platform. Once you have the code then you can apply pre-build algorithms. You can use http://bunkat.github.io/schedule/ to refine your logic. Hope this helps. If not then paste your code.

Comment: Did you understand last conditions?

Comment: Yes I did and you will also be able to work it out once you have satisfied above conditions. Work on solve able questions first. Last one isn't any different